# EF Core: detect table renaming

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I had to change my entities by adding a base class.
Before, I had this :

```
public virtual DbSet<EmailRequest> RefundEmailRequests { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<EmailRequestState> EmailRequestHistory { get; set; }
```

And change to this :

```
public virtual DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<RequestState> RequestHistory { get; set; }
```

The builder:

```
private void ConfigureRequest(EntityTypeBuilder<Request> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Requests");

    builder.HasKey(s => s.Id);

    builder.HasMany(s => s.History)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey("RequestId")
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    builder.HasDiscriminator<string>("Type")
        .HasValue<EmailRequest>(EmailRequest.Type)
        .HasValue<ExternalRequest>(ExternalRequest.Type);

    builder.Ignore(e => e.CurrentState);
}

private void ConfigureRequestState(EntityTypeBuilder<RequestState> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("RequestStates");

    builder.Property<int>("Id")
        .IsRequired();

    builder.HasKey("Id");

    builder.HasDiscriminator<string>("Type")
        .HasValue<Domain.States.Request.Received>(Domain.States.Request.Received.Type)
        .HasValue<Domain.States.Request.Processing>(Domain.States.Request.Processing.Type)
        .HasValue<Domain.States.Request.Duplicate>(Domain.States.Request.Duplicate.Type)
        .HasValue<Domain.States.Request.Rejected>(Domain.States.Request.Rejected.Type)
        .HasValue<Domain.States.Request.FailedProcessing>(Domain.States.Request.FailedProcessing.Type)
        .HasValue<Domain.States.Request.Processed>(Domain.States.Request.Processed.Type);
}
```

`EmailRequest` now inherits from `Request` (same principle for States)

When adding the migration, I notice that EF detected the renaming for `RequestState` but not for Request.

```
migrationBuilder.DropTable(
    name: "EmailRequests",
    schema: "refunds");

migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
    name: "EmailRequestStates",
    schema: "refunds",
    newName: "RequestStates");
```

How ? What can I do to detect the renaming ?

Answer (score -1):

> `EmailRequest` now inherits from `Request`

You can't rename a table into an existing one. You'll need to copy the data from the dropped one:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(
@"
    INSERT INTO Requests
    SELECT * FROM refunds.EmailRequests;
");

migrationBuilder.DropTable(
    name: "EmailRequests",
    schema: "refunds");
```

Comment: I'm not renaming into an existing one... And I'd like the "Add-Migration" efcore command to do it automatically. It's apparently doing it already for one table but not the other one, that's why I'm wondering how

Comment: If EF can match either the table name or the class name, it will generate a rename. Otherwise, you'll have to rewrite that part of the migration to use `RenameTable()` instead. Issue [#5826](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/5826) may help here.

Comment: If you insist on getting EF to rename it (seems silly when you can just edit the migration), you can do it in two steps 1) Use `ToTable()` or `[Table]` to point to the new table and generate a migration. 2) rename the class and remove the `ToTable()` or `[Table]` and generate another migration.