# EF-Core doesn't recognize table name changes in migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm using Entity Framework Core for establishing a SQLite database connection, I'm also using migrations to maintain my schema changes over versions.

I have two tables `PrivilegeElevationSettings` & `PrivilegeElevationApps` so when I changed the name of the `PrivilegeElevationSettings` table to `PESettings`, then successfully performing `add migration + update database`, I started getting a runtime exception

> No such table: PrivilegeElevationSettings

When I tried to read the migration class, I see no command for renaming the old table or even drop/create for a new one, it seems like EF Core doesn't recognize table name changes in migrations.

DataContext:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<PESettings> PESettings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PrivilegeElevationApp> PrivilegeElevationApps { get; set; }
    
    public DataContext() : base()
    {
        //Ignored
        EnsureBaseConfigExist();
    }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.Migrate();
        Database.OpenConnection();
        EnsureBaseConfigExist();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {       
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("my connection string");
        }
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PrivilegeElevationApp>().HasOne(pea => pea.PESettings).WithMany(pes => pes.PrivilegeElevationApps)
            .HasForeignKey(pea => pea.PESettingsId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Initial entities:

```
[Table("PrivilegeElevationSettings")]
public class PrivilegeElevationSettings
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } = 1;
    
    public List<PrivilegeElevationApp> PrivilegeElevationApps { get; set; } = new List<PrivilegeElevationApp>();
}

[Table("PrivilegeElevationApps")]
public class PrivilegeElevationApp
{
    [Key]
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("PrivilegeElevationSettings")]
    public int PrivilegeElevationSettingsId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public PrivilegeElevationSettings PrivilegeElevationSettings { get; set; }
}
```

Renamed entities:

```
[Table("PESettings")]
public class PESettings
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } = 1;
    
    public List<PrivilegeElevationApp> PrivilegeElevationApps { get; set; } = new List<PrivilegeElevationApp>();
}

[Table("PrivilegeElevationApps")]
public class PrivilegeElevationApp
{
    [Key]
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("PESettings")]
    public int PESettingsId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public PESettings PESettings { get; set; }
}
```

Migration Class:

```
public partial class Change_PETableName_Test : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_PrivilegeElevationApps_PESettings_PrivilegeElevationSettingsId",
            table: "PrivilegeElevationApps");

        migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
            name: "PrivilegeElevationSettingsId",
            table: "PrivilegeElevationApps",
            newName: "PESettingsId");

        migrationBuilder.RenameIndex(
            name: "IX_PrivilegeElevationApps_PrivilegeElevationSettingsId",
            table: "PrivilegeElevationApps",
            newName: "IX_PrivilegeElevationApps_PESettingsId");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_PrivilegeElevationApps_PESettings_PESettingsId",
            table: "PrivilegeElevationApps",
            column: "PESettingsId",
            principalTable: "PESettings",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_PrivilegeElevationApps_PESettings_PESettingsId",
            table: "PrivilegeElevationApps");

        migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
            name: "PESettingsId",
            table: "PrivilegeElevationApps",
            newName: "PrivilegeElevationSettingsId");

        migrationBuilder.RenameIndex(
            name: "IX_PrivilegeElevationApps_PESettingsId",
            table: "PrivilegeElevationApps",
            newName: "IX_PrivilegeElevationApps_PrivilegeElevationSettingsId");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_PrivilegeElevationApps_PESettings_PrivilegeElevationSettingsId",
            table: "PrivilegeElevationApps",
            column: "PrivilegeElevationSettingsId",
            principalTable: "PESettings",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if EFC could detect the renaming of a table (maybe if it was a 2 step thing it could work out), but there's nothing stopping you editing the code of the migration to [perform it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.renametable?view=efcore-5.0)?

Comment: @CaiusJard I can absolutely edit the migration file no worries, however, I'm complaining about why EFCore didn't recognize my table-name changes?!!

Comment: I can see that database table rename is supported for SQLite databases https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations

Comment: Post the full commands please

Comment: Thing is, to detect something like a rename you'd need something that remains constant between the before and after that would allow EF to deduce that e.g. tblPerson used to be called tblIndividual. While some DBs may have something (e.g. in SQLServer a table's OBJECT_ID should persist unchanged across renames) that does, I don't guarantee that EF migrations leverage it, if it's even available in database X. Perhaps you should try changing only one of the `[Table("PESettings")]` attribute and the `class PESettings` at once so that EFC can see a change occur

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49430209/ef-core-detect-table-renaming seems relevant